# A databinding bug occurs on specific Android device

Tags: android, data-binding

## Problem

In my activity, there are two views: **A** and **B**. I use **databinding** to control their visibility.

**View A**
`android:visibility="@{model.attr==1?View.GONE:View.VISIBLE}”`

**View B**

`android:visibility="@{model.attr!=1?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE}”`

Then, I packed a **release** Apk, ran it on **JinLi** and **QiKu** android device, but found that the two views's visibility was opposite: A is invisible and B is visible. Yes, do not be surprise, A and B logic are the same.

## Tips

Do not come too early to conclude that I make some mistakes of using databinding. Let me explain some more details:

- The problem only occurs on the above two android device.
- When I pack a debug version(i,e. **debug.apk**), the problem disappears.
- When I change the B's visibility declaration code with
  `android:visibility="@{model.attr==1?View.GONE:View.VISIBLE}”`, the problem disappears too.

## In short

- **JinLi** and **QiKu** goes wrong, the others works fine.
- **release.apk** goes wrong, **debug.apk** works fine.
- `android:visibility="@{model.attr!=1?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE}”` goes wrong, `android:visibility="@{model.attr==1?View.GONE:View.VISIBLE}”` works fine.

The problem is so strange that I have tried a few days. Does anyone meet such problem before? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: you should give value for attr in model class., use attr field as boolean in model class and check in xml layout @{model.attr?View.GONE:View.VISIBLE}

Comment: My first guess is that you have a different layout file that you are targeting toward these devices -- perhaps a different density bucket, portrait vs. landscape, screen size, etc.

Answer (score 2):

All Value should to be set and get By Java Class only, It's good to verify  that only in xml

XML File:

```
<RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/rides_relative_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/rides_relative_size"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="@{emptyCheck.isIsemptyview? View.VISIBLE: View.GONE}">
        </RelativeLayout>
```

To Set and Get Value in Java Class:

```
public class EmptyView extends BaseObservable {

    /**
     * The isEmptyView list check if it true or false by using get Ride Offered list
     */
    boolean isemptyview = false;

    /**
     * Gets {@see #isemptyview}.
     *
     * @return {@link #isemptyview}
     */
    @Bindable
    public boolean isIsemptyview() {
        return isemptyview;
    }

    /**
     * Sets {@see #isemptyview}
     *
     * @param isemptyview (@link #isemptyview}
     */
    public void setIsemptyview(boolean isemptyview) {
        this.isemptyview = isemptyview;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.isemptyview);
    }
}
```

Note: Some Devices doesn't accept direct value in xml while condition checking

Comment: Hi Keerthivasan,  I am so grateful you provide a formal way to use condition checking in databinding and present condition checking is unacceptable in some special devices. Now the only thing puzzles me is why **release.apk** goes wrong, **debug.apk** works fine. Can you give some more suggestion?